# XML Serializer and Deserializer class for different xml file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have 2 different format of xml files that needs to serialize and deserialize using C#.

XML Files
Type 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tms_msg>
    <transaction>
        <message_string>Left Over</message_string>
    </transaction>
</tms_msg>
```

Type 2 :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tms_msg>
    <transaction>
        <message_string>
            <utc_date_time>0001-01-01T00:00:00</utc_date_time>
            <utctime>000000</utctime>
            <latitude/>
            <latitude_hemi/>
            <longitude/>
            <longitude_hemi/>
            <speed/>
            <heading>000</heading>
        </message_string>
    </transaction>
</tms_msg>
```

How can i serialize and deserialize the two different xml files?
I need a class that can seriaize and deserialize these xml files.

//updated code

```
public class MessageReceiver 
{
    private MessageQueue _queue;
    private readonly string _queueName;

    public MessageReceiver()
    {
        this._queueName = @".\Private$\to_dispatch";
    }

    public void StartRead()
    {
        _queue = new MessageQueue(_queueName);
        _queue.PeekCompleted += QueuePeekCompleted;

    }

    private void QueuePeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = _queue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);         
        message.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(tms_msg) });
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The message was: {0}", message.Id));
        var m = message.Body;            
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The QueuePeek is completed message was: {0}", message.Id));      
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _queueName;
    }
}
```

I am using in the MSMQ messaging queue scenario.

Thanks,
Binod

Answer (score 1):

You can make `message_string` as dynamic in `transaction`. See below:

```
[XmlRoot("tms_msg")]
public class TmsMsg
{
    [XmlElement("transaction")]
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    [XmlElement("message_string")]
    public dynamic MessageString { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize:

```
public void Deserialize()
{
    TmsMsg msg = null;
    var msgDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    using (var stream = new FileStream("Type2.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TmsMsg));
        msg = ser.Deserialize(stream) as TmsMsg;
    }

    // type 1 : message_string element has a xml text node
    // type 2 : message_string element has a xml elements
    foreach (var node in msg.Transaction.MessageString)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            msgDict.Add("message_string", node.Value);
        }
        else if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            msgDict.Add(node.Name, node.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a typical scenario for MSMQ. I have added the class MessageReceiver that is going to use the xmlformatter. Please find the updated code. I cannot check the xml node type.

Comment: Perhaps someone else might want to help you now. Had you provided proper information/background in *original* question itself, I would not have proceeded in other direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it is working.
Change the following in above code.

```
[XmlElement("message_string")]
public dynamic message_string{ get; set; }
```

to

```
[XmlElement(typeof(string)), XmlElement(typeof(message_string))]
public dynamic message_string{ get; set; }
```

and change the class name Message_String to message_string.